# Need help changing cell values when cell in same row changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help automatically changing cells containing a certain value whenever a specific cell on same row changes value.

[image: example]

E.g whenever a cell in B column changes = change TRUE to FALSE on that specific row.

---

---

---

My VBA knowledge is pretty much nonexistent and Im certainly a beginner.

Im fairly sure that Worksheet.Change is what Im looking for and I've been trying out some code I've found here on SO, such as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each x In Target
    Cells(x.Row, 3).Value = "False"
Next 
End Sub
```

I know though that this doesn't replace specific values in whatever column the cells are.

I've been trying out silly things like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each x In Target
If Cells(x.Row, x.Column).Value = "TRUE" Then Value = "FALSE"
Next
End Sub
```

But of course it doesnt work.

Think you could point me out a direction of what I should be researching?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Quick answer is that yes this can be done. What you need to do for us to help you is first make an attempt on trying to revolve your query. If that doesn't work, post here what you have tried so far. We can then guide you on how you can achieve you goal

Comment: So what is it that you actual want to do? i.e. do you want all **TRUE** changed to **FALSE** on the row if the value changes in cell **B**

Comment: Yes exactly. Lets say B8 changes value, then all TRUE on row 8 changes to FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `change` event sub on the sheet where you have your data with the code below. I think that should do the trick

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim oCell As Range
    
    ' Check if change was in column B
    If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Turn off events so that when we make a change on the sheet, this event is not triggered again
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Set the range to include all column in Target row
    Set oRng = Target.Parent.Range("C" & Target.Row & ":" & Target.Parent.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address)
    
    ' Loop through all cells to change the value
    For Each oCell In oRng
        If Trim(LCase(oCell.Value)) = "true" Then
            oCell.Value = "FALSE"
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Enable events again
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```